# iOs Core Data Can't find model for source store third party classes

Tags: ios, core-data, model, database-migration

I'm trying to migrate my core data model by creating a new model version and adding new attributes to this model.

When I try to call addPersistentStoreWithType y get this error:

```
ERROR EN STORE CREATION: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134130 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 134130.)" UserInfo=0x2092d8e0 {URL=---------, metadata={
    NSPersistenceFrameworkVersion = 419;
    NSStoreModelVersionHashes =     {
        Conversation = <70d77201 17a127ac 55faa8c1 bc5e7827 54bf522d 2de0399c 1be14790 960ffeec>;
        ConversationMessage = <de645809 d140481f 2cf733da d75676a6 4569e6eb 4b5d7d0d 3c0a1841 4e4b2e6c>;
        XMPPCapsCoreDataStorageObject = <fcc8a450 20ad494a 3d9079f2 42eddbf4 6fdda8f1 5ffd78b6 70adb56d e120d7ae>;
        XMPPCapsResourceCoreDataStorageObject = <b4ad78f7 b849a2a8 4193de79 0b80bc86 94e575f4 7e821033 a785a017 c079e928>;
        XMPPGroupCoreDataStorageObject = <2d9d5e0b d7f6f74d 918cb9af f0fe44a4 fae60105 8144ccd0 112d0729 cead71eb>;
        "XMPPMessageArchiving_Contact_CoreDataObject" = <b35921c6 4d8667a9 39c46e41 b04053e9 2b2b2836 db2d9621 b37085a4 4437819f>;
        "XMPPMessageArchiving_Message_CoreDataObject" = <55ad74f0 602bd856 0a324688 c8f8d0e3 af1ba3ff adf512a3 de40f457 037acf23>;
        XMPPResourceCoreDataStorageObject = <e31f4b20 a3c302b6 7b2a74e1 2737e8cb d440ae9a 5bfb503b 32330cdd 17a98978>;
        XMPPRoomMessageCoreDataStorageObject = <e93f6bf3 51ecd04c 083c2478 35c336cb 245370ad 495268d5 e8324e34 af225773>;
        XMPPRoomMessageHybridCoreDataStorageObject = <13824bff 7a0977e0 5f6d47e3 29364758 76864702 329c31e7 02e1d2dc 01ad37de>;
        XMPPRoomOccupantCoreDataStorageObject = <2848335c 9cf626d6 44c5fe10 2c01a746 329d3e3b b785cd89 81949a40 28376f5c>;
        XMPPUserCoreDataStorageObject = <0ef429b0 41998c3a 496ab11a 26bde9ac 7d1a929f 9d7ea102 9ece131d b5a6890c>;
        XMPPvCardAvatarCoreDataStorageObject = <66d4bf5e 05ea2ec1 f355fcd4 32dcdd55 9288a6f0 68d8c045 6c13b9c6 ac300d7a>;
        XMPPvCardCoreDataStorageObject = <adac5b15 e1713a10 bcd16518 eff333ee 4543e45c 13ae60ac ce8bc593 f9b4d1ad>;
        XMPPvCardTempCoreDataStorageObject = <8a708229 823759d9 1ff41f51 3d9913d1 6ae42b49 b0c94c6b 40b41093 51840e6b>;
    };
    NSStoreModelVersionHashesVersion = 3;
    NSStoreModelVersionIdentifiers =     (
        ""
    );
    NSStoreType = SQLite;
    NSStoreUUID = "E3F6E3A8-FCF0-4819-BD4F-9FD14DDA1254";
    "_NSAutoVacuumLevel" = 2; }, reason=Can't find model for source store}
```

I think the reason is that all classes that starts with XMPP are from an third party library, and this classes are not being found in the new source model.

I don't know how to migrate third party models, i tried to delete this classes from de database but they don't exist in the same database...

## EDIT

I discovered what gone wrong, i'm calling in the managedObjectModel this method:

```
managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
```

But i need to create de managedObjectModel like this:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"name" ofType:@"momd"];
NSURL *momURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:momURL];
```

The problem is that now i already have this entities mixed... How can i separate them?